About music composition AI
I’m looking for a generative AI that can create music, similar to how an AI generates images based on prompts. For example, I want to analyze Mozart’s compositions to extract his musical characteristics and compositional techniques as a theoretical framework, which I would then input as a prompt to a composition AI. I hope to listen to the generated music and provide further instructions to gradually refine the piece. Is there already such an AI available? Do you have any recommendations?

For famous composers, one can use prompts such as:

create music in the style of Mozart

E.g., see https://www.udio.com/songs/31ogTLtiezURbCqput9rfZ

Or can use some older music generation models attempt something similar, e.g. from https://music.stackexchange.com/q/137768/2589:

Generative AI has been working on mimicking the styles of historic composers like Beethoven or Bach for some time. Andy Bonner CommentedOct 22 at 15:24

but afaik the generated music doesn't sound as good (and they tend to generate MIDI, not the actual audio output).
